# Scrapy CSV export shows the same data in all rows

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the following html code:

```
<ul class="results-list" id="search-results">
<li>
<h3 class="name">First John</h3>
<div class="details">
<a href="mailto:example@mail.com" class="email">email</a>
&nbsp;
<span class="phone">999999999</span>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<h3 class="name">Second John</h3>
<div class="details">
<a href="mailto:example@mail.com" class="email">email</a>
&nbsp;
<span class="phone">999999999</span>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

When I run my spider, I get 2 rows, containing the same information. I have name,email,phone columns and for example in the name column for both I would get:
First John,Second John.

My Scrapy code is the following:

```
people= response.xpath('//ul[@class="results-list"]/li')
        for person in people:
            item = SpiderItem()
            item['Name'] = person.xpath(
                '//h3/text()').extract()
            item['Email'] = person.xpath(
                '//div[@class="details"]/a/@href').extract()
            item['Phone'] = person.xpath(
                '//div[@class="details"]/span[@class="phone"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

However when I run `scrapy crawl MySpider -o output.csv` I get the same information in all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using absolute path on your xpath expressions, change them to:

```
for person in people:
    item = SpiderItem()
    item['Name'] = person.xpath(
        './/h3/text()').extract_first()
    item['Email'] = person.xpath(
        './/div[@class="details"]/a/@href').extract_first()
    item['Phone'] = person.xpath(
        './/div[@class="details"]/span[@class="phone"]/text()').extract_first()
    yield item
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works like a charm now.